# Read the data from a JSON file browsed from system

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, indexeddb

Is there any way to read the data from the browsed file. lets say
I have a file tag
`<input type = "file"/>` where i can browse the JSON file from system. I need to read the browsed file and push the information to Indexed DB. All this should be happening in client side using JavaScript or angular-JS.

Comment: Short answer is yes, you can do that, you can follow this example https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript

Comment: i think the way which i wrote is confusing, what i wanted is the file can be in any drive, i am browsing my website www.abc.com there is file-browse option where i can seelct the file from my machine, the selected json file should be read and push the data to indexedDB

Comment: If you take a look at the link in my previous comment, that's what you are looking for :)

Comment: I got the solution what am looking for, thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

With this code i was able to sort out the issue.

```
  angular.module('app').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;

                element.bind('change', function(e){
                   scope.myFile = element[0].files[0];
                   var reader = new FileReader();
                   reader.readAsText(scope.myFile);
                   var dataFromFile = reader.result;

                });
            }
        };  
    }]);
```